# How to include a templated typefef of a structure in a structure

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I am trying to include a templated (Of type structure) typedef in the same type structure.   The compiler is complaining that either the typedef or structure can't be found depending on what order I put them in the header file.

Example1  (./RobotControl.h:25:23: error: ‘InputUpdate_S’ was not declared in this scope)

```
class RobotControl
{
public:
  SomeFunctions();

  typedef Functor1<InputUpdate_S> InputUpdateFunctor_T;

   struct InputUpdate_S
   {
      InputUpdateType_E UpdateType;
      UInt8_T CoProcNum;
      UInt8_T PinNum;
      InputUpdateFunctor_T *callback;
   };
};
```

Example2  (error: ‘InputUpdateFunctor_T’ does not name a type)

```
class RobotControl
{
public:
  SomeFunctions();

   struct InputUpdate_S
   {
      InputUpdateType_E UpdateType;
      UInt8_T CoProcNum;
      UInt8_T PinNum;
      InputUpdateFunctor_T *callback;
   };

   typedef Functor1<InputUpdate_S> InputUpdateFunctor_T;

};
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fix it by forward declaring `InputUpdate_S` (i.e. write `struct InputUpdate_S;`) before the typedef, or not using the typedef within the `InputUpdate_S` but writing `Functor1<InputUpdate_S> *callback;` instead.